# C++ ASM Inline how to use boolean?

Tags: c++, inline-assembly, boolean

Say I got something like this..

```
bool isPatched;
```

I have a few other GUI's where I set `isPatched= true;` and `isPatched= false;`, `isPatched = !isPatched;`

```
void __declspec( naked ) test(void) { //
    __asm {
        PUSHAD
        PUSHFD

        MOV EAX, isPatched
        CMP EAX, 0
        je noPatched
            MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x77C]
            MOV John.oldA, EAX
            MOV EAX, John.A
            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x77C], EAX
            JMP finish
noPatched:
            PUSH EDX
            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x77C], EDX
        finish:
        POPFD
        POPAD

        JMP gotoAddressBack

    }
}
```

Is it possible to use `bool` operator in inline assembly?

I think it thinks isPatched is a label.. from this error message.
`error C2094: label 'isPatched' was undefined`

Comment: `test eax,0` will cause `je` to jump at all times.

Comment: oh..... I must of used `CMP` then right?

Comment: `isPatched != isPatched` is always false. Did you mean `= !`?

Comment: yes opps `isPatched = !isPatched`

Comment: @SSpoke: Either use `cmp eax, 0` or use `test eax, eax`.

Comment: What compiler? As inline assembler is not a standard part of C or C++

Comment: I am using the compiler that's shipped with VC++ 2010, Which supports inline assembly.. same as my old VC++ 6.0 did. But I can't seem to find any good tutorial sites or examples of many different possible operations using inline assembly in C++

Comment: @SSpoke: you'd probably find it easier looking up reverse engineering tutorials, this will take ASM to C++, but will give you an understanding of how to do the constructs.

Comment: @Necrolis Yeah I found out, my best hope is to use converters that convert like ollydbg asm to C++ asm.. those actually showed me not much.. other then labels and 0x's to hexadecimals

Comment: @SSpoke: well those won't teach you anything, I'm talking about proper reverse engineering, that is assembly to proper high(er) level constructs, like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff538086.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to `TEST` or `CMP`. `TEST` is the easiest in this case:

```
XOR EAX,EAX
MOV AL,isPatched //isPatched would be a byte, hence we need correct operand sizes
TEST EAX,EAX
JE NotSet
Set:
//handle true case
JMP End
NotSet:
//handle false case
End:
//continue
```

Depending on other cases you can also use `SUB`, `SETcc` or `MOVcc`

---

Your issue is one of scoping, `isPatched` is not in scope when used by the ASM, so it assumes it to be a `DWORD`, and then fails to find a memory label (the symbol name) for it when generating the addresses. You also need to use the correct operand size for `bool` as well.

A dirty litte test for MSVC

```
bool b = true;
int __declspec( naked ) test(void) {
    __asm {
        xor eax,eax
        MOV al, b
        TEST eax,eax
        JE NotSet
        mov eax,1
NotSet:
        RETN

    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", test());
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

this outputs 1 when `b` is `true`, or 0 when `b` is `false`.

Comment: yes haha, that i understand..  I'm wondering why `isPatched` a global boolean `bool` not being registered by inline ASM, that's not allowed?

Comment: @SSpoke: your problem is a scoping issue, but it reminded me of something else I needed to add, `bool`s are byte size....

Comment: Hmm i'm getting `error C2443: operand size conflict` with `MOV AL,isPatched`.

Comment: @SSpoke, then that means either a `bool` is not a byte on your system, or its a `BOOL`, not a `bool` (my example runs just fine).

Comment: `MOV AL, BYTE PTR isPatched` removed that error, but now caused again the error that isPatched label was undefined.. even though it's not a label.   Nice example above

Comment: @SSpoke: all symbols are called labels in assembly (its a memory label). with it little testing, its clear its a scoping issue, removing the definition of `b` from my example yields `C2443`, adding the size suffix after that yields `C2094`. try doing `extern bool isPatched` just before your asm block

Comment: oh my.. it was a case-sensitive bug with the variable. But all this helped me learn a bunch more useful stuff thank you.